# How do I keep a netmodule file from getting wiped on project clean in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, netmodules

I've inherited an Ektron 8.5 project and it requires that `saxon9api.netmodule` be left in the `/bin` folder along with `saxon9api.dll`

If I don't keep this `.netmodule` file in the bin, then the build fails.

However, when I clean the project in Visual Studio, the `.netmodule` file gets removed from the bin, and I have to reload it from SVN.

I tried to add a reference to the `.netmodule` file in Visual Studio to prevent this, but it won't allow me to add a reference to a `.netmodule` file.

What can I do to preserve this file in the build so it doesn't get wiped out by a project clean?

Comment: Have you tried adding the files to some location in your project? You could then change the build action in the selected files' property window  to none , and set the "copy to output directory" to be "copy always" or "copy if newer". This should always copy the file to the bin folder when you build.

Comment: You'll have to keep it out of the bin directory.  Surely it doesn't *have* to be there but you give no hints.  Using a prebuild event to xcopy it there is the simplest alternative.

Comment: the issue was that it had to be in the same directory as saxon9api.dll, which was in /bin, but you're both right.. I just moved the dll to another location and adjusted the project reference. it now works. if you drop an answer i'll accept it